# Using the ACL library to manage permissions for action paramaters

Tags: php, acl, phalcon

I am using Phalcon as my framework of choice. I have hit a bit of a road block when it comes to structuring my website. I would like to use ACL to manage permissions to my website. But it seems ACL does not allow my to set permission values for 'parameters'.

Say I am creating a website that has user created 'groups' which only users with the correct permissions (set in the ACL) can view.

It might work something like this: website.com/groups/view/MyGroup

Group being the controller, view being the action and "MyGroup" being the parameter for the action defining which group to view.

I can only set the access permission for the groups controller or view action. Not the parameter.

Ideally, [I'd use the database adapter for ACL](https://github.com/phalcon/incubator/tree/master/Library/Phalcon/Acl/Adapter#database) and I would create a new user group for every group created in my app. I could have hundreds of groups, each with own set of users. I can reuse the 'groups' controller code for every group, because we always use the same controller/actions, except we point to different groups by changing the parameter.

How could I achieve this using Phalcons ACL library ? Maybe I need to structure things differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Phalcons ACL is based on 'Resources', in which a Resource can technically be anything you desire, you're not limited to controllers only.

http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/api/Phalcon_Acl.html

Comment: Man I wish the documentation was more obvious about this. It keeps using Controllers and Actions as part of its examples!